# My PyQt5 script is skipping a line inside a function

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make a simple browser GUI for learning purposes with PyQt5. A function that I want is to have in the status bar a text "Online". If the user clicks somewhere else from the browser and the application loses focus, a message will appear in the status bar indicating that, and after a few seconds the browser will change the url to google.

If I run the following code everything works fine as expected, when app loses focus it navigates to google. However, the message "Application lost focus ..." doesn't appear in the statusbar. It simply skips that line. If I remove the seturl and time.sleep line, the script will change the text as expected.

Why is it skipping that line? (Line 55)

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QFrame ,QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class VLine(QFrame):
    # a simple VLine, like the one you get from designer
    def __init__(self):
        super(VLine, self).__init__()
        self.setFrameShape(self.VLine|self.Sunken)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setFocus()
        app.focusChanged.connect(self.on_focusChanged)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://stackoverflow.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.date = QDate.currentDate()
        
        font =  QFont('Arial', 16, QFont.Bold)
        self.statusBar().setFont(font)

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        self.lbl1 = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl1.setStyleSheet('border: 0; color:  red;')
        self.lbl1.setFont(font)
        

        self.statusBar().reformat()
        self.statusBar().setStyleSheet('border: 0; background-color: #FFF8DC;')
        self.statusBar().setStyleSheet("QStatusBar::item {border: none;}") 
        
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())    # <---
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.lbl1)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(VLine())

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Time: ' + label_time + ' || Date: ' + self.date.toString('dd.MM.yyyy'))
    
    def on_focusChanged(self):
        if self.isActiveWindow() == False:
            print(f"\nwindow is the active window: {self.isActiveWindow()}")
            self.lbl1.setText('Application lost focus. Returning to Google in 5 seconds')
            time.sleep(5)
            self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://google.com'))
            self.lbl1.setText('Online')
        else:
            print(f"window is the active window: {self.isActiveWindow()}")
            self.lbl1.setText('Online')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Browser')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: A suggestion. Titles should summarize the actual issue in the most clear way possible: "my script is skipping a line" is almost meaningless; in fact, it was *not* "skipping" any line at all, the problem was that your `if` condition wasn't met. A more proper title could have been "Unable to detect focus change of window" or something like that. Then, StackOverflow doesn't support line counting in code, so we don't have a straightforward way to know which line you're referring to (we have to copy and paste in an editor that supports line count).

Comment: @musicamante thank you for the tips, noted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing how the `focusChanged` signal works: it emits a signal regarding the focus changes **within** the program.

What you need is to override the [`changeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent) of the window and intercept an `ActivationChange` event type.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.ActivationChange:
            # ...
```

That said, **NEVER** put a blocking function within the main thread.

Remove the `time.sleep` and never think about using it again for this kind of things.

Add a function for that redirect, and create a QTimer that you can start when losing focus (and stop if regaining it again before the timeout).

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.focusLostTimer = QTimer(
            interval=5000, singleShot=True, timeout=self.focusRedirect)

    def focusRedirect(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://google.com'))

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.ActivationChange:
            if not self.isActiveWindow():
                self.focusLostTimer.start()
            else:
                self.focusLostTimer.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful